# How to interact and check with multiple variables at once kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

There is such task: such fields as a `name`, a `surname` and a `patronymic` arrive at an input.

In the simplest case, all these fields are filled with data, so their output looks like this:

```
"name" + "surname" + "patronymic"
```

However, there are times when, for example, the last name field is missing, so the output should look like this:

```
"name" + "patronymic"
```

Another case, when there is no patronymic, in this case it should be displayed like this:

```
"name" + "surname"
```

The same thing with the `name`, it may be missing, how it should look, I think you already guessed it.

I understand that you most likely need to somehow use `if-else` to achieve the desired result for all cases, but it seems to me, will be too much code. Is it possible to somehow solve this problem and process all the options?

Comment: What is the input format in this case? Do you have a list of strings? And do you want to join them with spaces in between?

Comment: @ArpitShukla this is not a list, but several variables separately, and yes, they must be located between each other with a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val name = "name"
val surname = "surname"
val patronymic = "patronymic"

val result = listOf(name, surname, patronymic)
  .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
  .joinToString(" ")

println(result)
```

Or with a helper function:

```
fun List<String>.concatWithBlank() = this.filter { it.isNotBlank() }.joinToString(" ")

val result = listOf(name, surname, patronymic).concatWithBlank()
```

Comment: addition to this answer: if the `String`s are nullable you need to check on `!it.isNullOrBlank()` instead

Comment: @IvoBeckers correct!

Comment: @lukas.j thanks, 
your way is perfect for my case